# c# how to reveal the empty fields in minesweeper

Tags: c#, if-statement, tail-recursion, minesweeper

I'm currently working on creating a playable minesweeper and the basics are ready but I want to make it perfect. My problem is that now if you click on any field it reveals its content even if its an empty one and it feels kind of annoying to click all the field and I want to make it work like the real minesweeper. So if you click on an empty field I want to reveal ist surrounding as far as possible.
At the moment it looks something like this:

```
if (grid[x, y] == 0)
{
        if (x + 1 < lenght)
        {   //Right
            btn_grid[x + 1, y].Visible = false;
        }
        if (x - 1 > 0)
        {   //Left
            btn_grid[x - 1, y].Visible = false;
        }
        if (y + 1 < height )
        {   //Upper
            btn_grid[x, y + 1].Visible = false;
        }
        if (y - 1 > 0)
        {   //Lower
            btn_grid[x, y - 1].Visible = false;
        }
        if (x + 1 < sz && y + 1 < m)
        {   //Right-Upper
            btn_grid[x + 1, y + 1].Visible = false;
        }
        if (x + 1 < lenght && y - 1 > 0)
        {   //Right-Lower
            btn_grid[x + 1, y - 1].Visible = false;
        }
        if (x - 1 > 0 && y + 1 < height)
        {   //Left-Upper
            btn_grid[x - 1, y + 1].Visible = false;
        }
        if (x - 1 > 0 && y - 1 > 0)
        {   //Left-Lower
            btn_grid[x - 1, y - 1].Visible = false;
        }
}
```

this basicly reveals the other 8 fields. I made a lot of 'if' function to avoid the error of running out of the field (however it feels really clumsy so I wonder if there is a better way to do it).
Now I want to make some kind of recursive method so it keeps going around the field looking for 0 values (blank spaces) and keep doing it in its neighbourhood.

I tried something like:

```
void emptyspace(int x, int y) 
    {
        if (grid[x, y] == 0 && x + 1 < lenght && x - 1 > 0 && y + 1 < height && y - 1 > 0) 
        {
            btn_grid[x, y].Visible = false;
            emptyspace(x - 1, y - 1);
            emptyspace(x, y - 1);
            emptyspace(x + 1, y - 1);
            emptyspace(x + 1, y);
            emptyspace(x + 1, y + 1);
            emptyspace(x, y + 1);
            emptyspace(x - 1, y + 1);
            emptyspace(x - 1, y);
        }

    }
```

then I invited this method on the buttonclick action like such:

```
emptyspace(x,y);
```

but it does nothing so I wonder if I should call it different way or its just simply a dumb idea.

So I've been thinking for a while and asked my familiars if they can help but thats pretty much where we are right now.
So Any idea would be helpful.
Much appreciated and sorry for my bad English.

EDIT: I finally figured it out andt the solution look something like this:

```
public void emptyspace(int x, int y)
    {
        btn_grid[x, y].Visible = false;
        count++;
        if (grid[x, y] == 0)
        {
            if (x + 1 < sz)
                if (btn_grid[x + 1, y].Visible != false)
                    emptyspace(x + 1, y);

            if (y + 1 < m)
                if (btn_grid[x, y + 1].Visible != false)
                    emptyspace(x, y + 1);

            if (x - 1 > -1)
                if (btn_grid[x - 1, y].Visible != false)
                    emptyspace(x - 1, y);

            if (y - 1 > -1)
                if (btn_grid[x, y - 1].Visible != false)
                    emptyspace(x, y - 1);

            if (x + 1 < sz && y + 1 < m)
                if (btn_grid[x + 1, y + 1].Visible != false)
                    emptyspace(x + 1, y + 1);

            if (x - 1 > -1 && y + 1 < m)
                if (btn_grid[x - 1, y + 1].Visible != false)
                    emptyspace(x - 1, y + 1);

            if (x + 1 < sz && y - 1 > -1)
                if (btn_grid[x + 1, y - 1].Visible != false)
                    nullas(x + 1, y - 1);

            if (x - 1 > -1 && y - 1 > -1)
                if (btn_grid[x - 1, y - 1].Visible != false)
                    emptyspace(x - 1, y - 1);
        }
```

This works just as I intended!

Comment: Your recursive approach seems good to me, it should even be enough if you call the recursive method only for the 4 direct neighbors (and not the diagonal ones). Have you tried stepping through your code with the debugger and checking if the if-condition is true?

Comment: Your code seems fine overall. A few things though: 1) in the if-statement, make sure that current field is not already visible - 2) "x - 1 > 0 &&  y - 1 > 0" should be "x - 1 >= 0 &&  y - 1 >= 0" as the first item in array is at position 0 - 3) as Hinek said, debug. A simple way would be to print something inside the if-statement. Also, should it not be "btn_grid[x, y].Visible = true;" (instead of false)?

Comment: Why do you do `if (y - 1 > -1)` when you could just do `if (y > 0)` ?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this (pseudo-code):

```
queue = new Queue()
reveal clicked cell
enqueue(clicked cell)
while (queue is not empty)
{
    cell = dequeue()
    for each neighbor X of cell
    {
        if (X is revealed)
        {
            continue;
        }
        reveal X
        if X has no adjacent mine
        {
           enqueue X
        }
    }
}
```